# exporting the port as a variable from one file to use it in another in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a chat application using socket.io using Express. In "bin/www" file I have define the port to be used.I have export the variable "port". The code goes as:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
module.exports.port = port;
```

In another file "app.js" I want to use the same variable "port". so I imported the external file.While consoling its showing as variable "port" not defined :

```
var serverfile= require('./bin/www');
console.log(serverfile.port);
```

Is the way of exporting the variable wrong?

Comment: what your function `normalizePort()` do ? can you console.log your port var inside `./bin/www` ?

Comment: normalizePort() came as a function of express when I generated the express project